# 'su root' succeeded for root on /dev/??? - SunOS logging

Tags: linux, logging, sunos

I have a log like this in */var/log/authlog* :

```
<date> <server> su: [ID 366847 auth.notice] 'su root' succeeded for root on /dev/???
```

and in /var/adm/sulog

```
SU 12/12 11:13 + ??? root-root
```

It is repeated every 2 minutes, but there is no scheduled job active for this purpose.

1) Is it normal a **su root from root** (maybe something directly from SunOS)?

2) What's the meaning of **/dev/???** , why these '**???**'?

3) Can i do something to get more information about the origin of this 'su root'?

Thanks.

Comment: The question is ok, but you posted to the wrong site. Use `superuser.com` for questions about hard and software which are *not* related to *programming*

Comment: Oh ok sorry .. Thanks a lot, i will post in superuser so.